# Visualisation of electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, velocity, measurement-problem, observables

first things first, I'm not by any means a physicist nor a student of physics. I study graphic design. Theme of my bachelor thesis is visualisation of physical and mathematical phenomenons, long story short I'm trying to create aesthetically pleasing depiction of electron.

Hopefully I made my homework, and got very rudimentary concept of orbitals all right. I also watched new Cosmos where in episode 5, electron of hydrogen is depicted, i tried to create similar depiction using Processing.

In Cosmos, Mr. Degrasse talks about "quantum leaps" where electron leaps from higher energy orbitals(and he exactly uses word orbital, not orbit) to the lower energy, and vice versa.

Cosmos depiction: (Sorry for gif's stutters, renderer problem probably)

[image: cosmos]

And here's my depiction: (leap, happens every 1.5 seconds, and always leaps from lower to higher, I haven't figured out other way yet. While Cosmos' electron's trajectory is depicted as flat surface, angle of mine changes with every leap. Due to aesthetics I omitted proportions of electron compared to nucleus)

[image: orb]

**My questions are:**

1. Does electron have any kind of velocity, does it "move"? Or does it teleport "around" according to orbital probability function? And hence depiction in Cosmos is not correct?
2. If it is not possible to pin down exact position of electron at given moment, is this way of depicting electron utterly wrong?
3. Would large sphere filled with "points" that represent probability of electron's position depict electron's behaviour better? Considering we are working with Hydrogen's atom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The electron does not move - it has no well-defined position in the orbital state, and hence no well-defined momentum. Neither does it "teleport" around - as long as it is not interacting with something that forces it to be at a definite position, its state is "smeared" all over the electron as an [electron cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).
2. Yes, this is essentially the [Bohr model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model), which is known to be false (and, since it is *still* taught in schools, the source for *many* a confusion about electron orbitals). Please do not perpetuate it.
3. Why points? If you insist on visualizing it, the "smooth" pictures the Wikipedia page on atomic orbitals has are far better suited, for example:

[image]

Comment: How does leap happen then? Does electron leap into every possible position? (as long as Orbital's probability allows "landing zone") Does electron exist in every possible position? Hence the smear?

Comment: @Monocheddar: The electron has a *probability to be found* in every possible position. Until you look, it *exists* in neither of them, but only in a superposition of them - you *cannot* say where the electron is as long as it occupies the orbital state (and since the orbital states are those stable under time evolution, those are the states all electrons will be in in the real world), only where it *can be found*. One imagines it "smeared out" over the volume in which the probability to find it is non-neglegible.

Comment: "The electron does not move - it has no well-defined position in the orbital state, and hence no well-defined momentum." - Monocheddar should understand, though, that you can measure different variables for an electron, and that this statement is specifically meant to apply to precise energy measurements (each 'orbital state' has a well-defined energy). If instead you chose to periodically measure position and momentum to the most precise degree allowed by the uncertainty principle, you could see it "move" between successive measurements (not sure exactly what this would look like).

Comment: @ACuriousMind You are wrong, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yii1u2Lz-II electrons do move, the have a well defined angular momentum. "it has no well-defined position in the orbital state, and hence no well-defined momentum" . Thats like saying: this car has no well defined position, therefor it doesnt move. http://www.photographymad.com/files/images/shutter-speed-motion-blur.jpg Do you even understand what you are saying bruv?

Comment: @eromod The phrasing in the answer is a bit off - it is not *because* it has no well-defined position that it has no well-defined momentum, but it is nevertheless true that the orbitals are stationary states with well-defined energy and angular momentum, but no well-defined position or linear momentum. In no meaningful sense of the word does an electron in an orbital "move".

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1)If I measure the position of an electron around a hydrogen atom at midnight, then measure it again a minute later, will it be in the  exact same spot? 2) are orbitals the shape of electrons or do electrons reside within the orbitals?

Comment: @eromod 1. You will most likely measure it somewhere else, but by measuring its position you changed its state from the orbital state to a position state, which is no longer stationary. 2. More the latter - "orbital" is just the name for the quantum state the electrons occupy. The shapes one sees drawn are basically the wavefunctions associated to these states, i.e. the area where the probability of detecting the electron is large if one were to measure its position.

Comment: So if your measurements show that its in different locations at different times, why would you insist that they dont move? Doesnt your belief contradict experimental data? Or are you saying that the act of measurement "IS" what moves it? Without measurement it wouldn't move?

Comment: @eromod I insist that they don't "move" because this is not classical motion, there is no continuous change of a well-defined position in the interval between the two detections, it is simply the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics kicking in. It's not useful to call that "motion" because it implies a classical picture that simply is not the case. If you want to discuss this further, you could [drop by in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)