# What is currently the most accurate visual depiction of the atom? What does an atom look like so far as we know?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, photons, atoms

During my undergrad studies, I am constantly told how Bohr's image is wrong, for example, and how all my pre-notions of an atom are bad. Still, I've never been shown what the accepted contemporary model/picture actually is? What is currently the most complete visual depiction of the atom?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148822/50583

Answer (score 2):

The [Bohr model is still used a lot](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2) when images of an atom are required, because it is visual in the usual sense of images we have, and because at the limit the strict hydrogen solutions which do not have orbits, [but orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html), probability loci, correspond in quantum numbers to the Bohr orbits.

Here is a "[picture of the shadow of an atom"](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/73-first-look-at-an-atoms-shadow)

[image: shadow]

> “We’re used to objects casting shadows, but they’re made up of atoms,” he says. “I wondered what the shadow would look like if you kept peeling back atoms until you had just one.” So he isolated a single ytterbium atom in a vacuum chamber, shined a laser at it, and focused in on the resulting 450-nanometer gap of darkness that landed on his digital image sensor. In July he released the image above: the first-ever view of an atomic shadow.